# Python outputs wrong value

Tags: python

From the log file I need the last lines. I listed them in [-1:-7]

```
f_read = open("C:\logs.txt", "r")
status = f_read.readlines()[-1:-7]
print(status)
```

Python outputs

```
[]
```

How can I make it show strings?

Comment: Try `[-1:-7:-1]` i.e. step size of `-1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[-7:-1]
it must be from lower to upper